# Delphi: Блики и мигание TImage

Tags: delphi

Задача состоит в перетаскивании картинок TImage на форме с помощью мышки.

И проблема состоит в том, что когда эти элементы перетаскиваются, они начинают мигать, появляются блики.

Возможно ли это как-то убрать, чтобы не было никаких бликов и мигания изображения во время перетаскивания?

Delphi 2007

Comment: избавлению от этого эффекта, если мне не изменяет память, посвящена  самая  первая лабораторная по программированию графики в институтах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На гл. форме в свойствах выставьте DoubleBuffered в true. Если такого свойства нет, то [двойную буфферизацию вам придется реализовывать самостоятельно.](http://subscribe.ru/archive/comp.soft.prog.delphiprogr/200712/14121853.html)

Comment: согласен с Человеком_Борща. Тут только двойная буфферизация поможет. Сам раньше на делфи работал, возникала проблема с миганием изображения, потом двойная буферизация помогла избавиться от такого неприятного эффекта).